# Curved lines in a picture (Photography)

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, imaging, curvature, lenses

My problem is when I take a picture (a close one) the straight edge looks a little curved. In a standard camera, like a CyberShot.

I would like to know if there is some relationship between the curvature of the glass and that effect or if you know more information about that.

Comment: Talking about [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_aberration#Distortion_of_the_image)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes the image distortions can be mapped and corrected for.
You could do this analytically just from the lens design and the scene - but you would  need a detailed optical design for the lens.

The easier way is to take a picture of a calibration target (typically a chess board or array of dots) and then map the distortions in software and apply the same corrections to your image.

See [opencv](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html) for [examples](http://opencv.itseez.com/trunk/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html)